# Cannot override final method Exception::getPrevious()

Tags: php

I got CMS and trying to install it, but when i try to login i got error

Cannot override final method Exception::getPrevious()

```
Fatal error: Cannot override final method Exception::getPrevious() in C:\wamp\www\uis-online\application\exceptions\applicationException.php on line 41
```

Does anyboy have idea what cause this error

code in this file is

```
class ApplicationException extends Exception
{
    protected $innerException;
    /**
     * Konstruktor
     * @return unknown_type
     */
    public function __construct($message, $code = 0, Exception $innerException = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, $code);

        if (!is_null($innerException))
        {
            $this->innerException = $innerException;
        }
    }
    public function getPrevious()
    {
        return $this->innerException;
    }

    // custom string representation of object
    public function __toString() {
        $exceptions_message = "";
        if($this->innerException != null && $this->innerException->getMessage() != "") {
            $exceptions_message = $this->innerException->__toString();
        }

        return $exceptions_message .__CLASS__ . ": [{$this->code}]: {$this->message}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Final methods cannot be override - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in the documentation the method you're trying to override is a final one.

```
final public Exception Exception::getPrevious ( void )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/exception.getprevious.php
According to the PHP manual you can't override final methods.

> PHP 5 introduces the final keyword, which prevents child classes from overriding a method by prefixing the definition with final. If the class itself is being defined final then it cannot be extended.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.final.php